# Thunderbird does not allow anymore to open url links with the predefined browser

Tags: windows-7, thunderbird

I'm just switched from XP to Seven. I have transferred my Firefox and Thunderbird profiles to my old XP pc to my new Seven pc.
Firefox and Thunderbird work as expected, apart that with Thunderbird now when I click on a url inside a message text nothing happens, while before the browser window was loaded and the url page opened.
What could be the problem source?

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to Menubar via Tools → Options → Advanced tab → Config editor
2. Look for **network.protocol-handler.external.http**
3. Set the value to `TRUE`.

Found via [Thunderbird does not open links if IE or Firefox is already open](http://getsatisfaction.com/mozilla_messaging/topics/thunderbird_does_not_open_links_if_ie_or_firefox_is_already_open) .